# How to get the available connected vertex in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I have a case: I want to get all the connected vertex (including the middle vertex) from a base vertex.

For example, the graph as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdpJh.png)

I want to query all the connected vertexes from vertex ("giggs"), and I also want to query the connected path. ex: "giggs"->"192.168.0.1"->"ronaldo"->"192.168.0.2"->"veri". I used query as below:

```
MATCH {class: ic, as: s, where: (title = 'giggs')}.(outE(){where: 'some condition'}.inV().inE(){where: 'some condition'}.outV()){class: %s, as: t, while: ($depth <= 5), where: ($matched.s != $currentMatch)} RETURN $paths
```

I can get all the target nodes, ex: "veri", but I don't know the preceding vertex of "veri" and the edge between "veri" and its preceding vertex.

So how I can write the query? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TRAVERSE both() FROM (SELECT EXPAND(s) FROM (MATCH {CLASS:ic, AS:s, WHERE:(name='giggs')} RETURN s))
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Thanks Bonizzi. If I use traverse, how can I add search condition on the edge? Since I need to add constraints since part edges match my query criteria. I go through the official document (http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Traverse.html), it looks I can only add condition on the vertex. But please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Thx

Comment: For example: MATCH {class: ic, as: s, where: (title = 'giggs')}.(outE(){where: 'occur_time between date('2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') and date('2018-01-27 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')'}.inV().inE(){where: 'occur_time between date('2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') and date('2018-01-27 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')'}.outV()){class: %s, as: t), where: ($matched.s != $currentMatch)} RETURN $paths, which has condition on edge like 'occur_time between date('2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') and date('2018-01-27 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')'.